# Service Stack [Required] Annotation does not work

Tags: c#, api, servicestack, data-annotations

I have a model and I have added a required annotation on it but it does not do anything. It does not throw any error. Do I have to add something to configuration to make sure annotations are fired.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

 [ApiMember(Description = "The student ID to lookup", IsRequired = true, ParameterType = "form")]
 [Required]
 public int? StudentId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Required]` attribute can be used in [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) data models to annotate non nullable fields but it does not have any effect on ServiceStack DTOs.

To validate DTOs it's recommended to use the [built-in Fluent Validation support](https://docs.servicestack.net/validation#validation-feature).